# Наверху vs. на верху

Tags: орфография

Согласно толковому словарю Ожегова, слово «наверху» - это наречие (сидеть наверху) и предлог (флаг наверху дома, гнездо наверху ели). В то же время есть существительное «верх», которое обозначает в числе прочего самую высокую часть чего-либо (верх того же дома, например). Выходит, мы вполне можем сказать,  что флаг находится на верху дома как на самой высокой его части. Написание при этом изменится со слитного на раздельное.
Объясните, пожалуйста, какой логикой следует руководствоваться в таких случаях при выборе варианта написания.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С различением наречий и сущ. с предлогом, действительно,проблемы нет. Но вот с предлогом НАВЕРХУ - есть.Его часто не видят. [Справочник по правописанию и стилистике](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/57/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Есть примечания к правилу: Примечание 1. Возможность вставки определяющего слова (ср.: вверх – в самый верх) не влечет за собой раздельного их написания. Раздельно эти слова пишутся только при наличии в самом предложении пояснительного слова к указанным существительным или по смыслу контекста, например: к низу платья, в глубь океана, в даль туманную, в начале осени, во веки веков, на веки вечные, повторить урок с начала (т. е. «от начала», а не «сперва»). Ср.: Науку изучают с азов, дружбу берегут с начала (пословица). Но: Нужно начать всё сначала (в значении «заново, опять, еще раз»).

Примечание 2. Некоторые из приведенных в данном пункте слов могут употребляться в функции предлогов при управляемом существительном, и в этих случаях сохраняется слитное написание, например: Внизу двери виден был свет (т. е. свет шел из-под двери, а не освещал низ двери); Вверху письма стояла дата (воспринимается значение наречного предлога, а не предметное значение «верх письма»). Ср. также: быть наверху блаженства, чувствовать себя наверху благополучия (с переносным значением слова наверху)

[infobos.ru](http://infobos.ru/tr/16759.html)
3. Чего, предлог с родительным падежом. В верхней части чего-нибудь. Флаг наверху дома.акцент на "сверху", а не вбит в верх дома Гнездо наверху ели.-акцент на значение "в верхней части ели", а не "прикреплено к верху ели".

Comment: >С различением наречий и сущ. с предлогом, действительно,проблемы нет. Но вот с предлогом НАВЕРХУ - есть.Его часто не видят.  
  
Можно пример сочетания, вызывающего такую проблему? Я то-то по-прежнему не понимаю, что тут сложного...

Comment: Да вот эти же слитные написания "наверху ели" и "наверху дома".Вы же засомневались в слитном написании? А это как раз пример , когда наверху-предлог и пишется слитно. (Где?)Наверху дома - так же, как и вокруг дома, посреди дома,впереди дома. Потому что нас интересует не верх дома как предмет, а верхнее положение в пространстве, т.е. это не сущ., а предлог.

Comment: Да какая в них сложность... Сказано ж, что возможно двоякое написание. 
Ладно, спасибо, я понял о чем речь идет.

Comment: Интересно; я не смогла найти это правило. Спасибо, Людмила. Возможно, я не слишком последовательно изложила суть проблемы, но Вы все правильно поняли.
Что меня удивляет, так это сочетания предлога "наверху" с "блаженством" и "благополучием". Выражения "быть на верху блаженства", "чувствовать себя на верху благополучия", в которых употреблено существительное "верх" в значении "наивысшая степень, крайнее состояние чего-либо", имеют смысл, по крайней мере мне так представляется. Но "наверху блаженства"... Не то чтобы у блаженства есть верхняя или нижняя часть, чтобы в ней находиться.

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу, в чем проблема.
Вы же требуемую логику и изложили.
Если "на чем" - "то на верху".
Если "где", то "наверху".

Разумеется, есть случаи, когда в зависимости от авторского смысла возможно двоякое написание.

Честно говоря, больше вопросов вызывают ваши слитные написания "наверху ели" и "наверху дома". Они безусловно возможны, но только во вполне конкретном значении. Когда что-то находится "**на** верхней части". А если "**в** верхней части" - уже есть сомнения.