# "На верху блаженства" или "наверху блаженства"

Tags: семантика

Позаимствовал вопрос с сайта для англоязычных пользователей, интересующихся русским языком.

Согласно [Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка](http://phraseology.academic.ru/1031/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0#) следует писать:

> "быть на верху блаженства".

Согласно    [Справочник по правописанию и стилистике](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/57/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9) следует писать:

> "быть наверху блаженства".

Англоязычный пользователь предположил, что

***"быть наверху блаженства" = быть в очень радостном состоянии.
"быть на верху блаженства" = быть в максимуме радости (лучше, чем до и после).***

Есть ли на самом деле смысловая разница в этих выражениях или они означают одно и то же?

Comment: Вы не весь вопрос видели.

Comment: Единственное, что меня в данном случае интересует, это наличие или отсутствие смысловой разницы при написании "на верху блаженства" и "наверху блаженства."

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В Нацкорпусе  28 примеров с раздельным написанием и 22 примера со слитным написанием:

(а) Он был наверху блаженства, на самом верху, он качался на остренькой спице блаженства (Василий Аксенов).

(б) За эту ночь, он... побывал на верху блаженства и на дне отчаяния. [Б. Л. Пастернак).

2) РАЗНИЦУ в значении между двумя  вариантами (наверху и на верху) определить  достаточно сложно. Например, "на верху горы" одинаково часто пишут как слитно, так и раздельно:

(а) А наверху горы, пред крыльцом кельи старца Иоанна, собрался полукруг людей, терпеливо и молча ожидающих утешения, и среди них ― Кожемякин (Максим Горький). Просидел наверху горы больше часа; видел молодого оленя с двумя ланями (Николай II. Дневники 1913-1916).

(б) Увидев знакомый виноградник и белый домик на верху горы, я почувствовал какую-то сладость ― именно сладость на сердце. [И. C. Тургенев. Не может укрыться город, стоящий на верху горы (Виктор Бондарев).

3) В некоторых случаях семантика всё-таки различна, но пользователи, как правило, ее не ощущают:

Наверху (чего-то) -  в верхней части предмета, на верху (чего-то) -  на плоской верхней площадке  предмета, если такая имеется. Например: на верху книжного шкафа стоят несколько бюстиков, стоять на верху стремянки, но: наверху стены  сделана надпись.

ВЫВОД

**Пишем так, как рекомендует Лопатин, то есть раздельно: на верху блаженства.** (Верх блаженства при этом можно рассматривать как верхний уровень чувств). **Для отвлеченного понятия смысловая разница между двумя формами написания однозначно отсутствует.**

Comment: Вера, разница между цифрами не очень большая, чтобы делать такой вывод. Вы искали в одном корпусе. Если поискать и других, разница вместе вообще маленькая: 33(34) -вместе, 35(36) раздельно.

Comment: Vera, а разница в семантике "на верху блаженства" и "наверху блаженства" есть?

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Даже для предметных существительных смысловую разницу трудно уловить, а здесь речь идет об отвлеченном понятии.

Answer (score 2):

Повтор вопроса. [Наверху vs. на верху](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24689/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d1%83-vs-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d1%83)

Видимо, это написание не устоявшиеся. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем повтор, Серж. Я хочу выяснить, появляется ли смысловая разница при разном написании, или её нет.

Comment: Матвей, если бы была какая-нибудь смысловая разница, словарями она фиксировалась бы.

Answer (score 1):

Существует устойчивое выражение "**верх блаженства**". Стало быть, сайт, который Вы упоминаете, отвечает совершенно правомерно.

Comment: Вы не весь вопрос видели.

Comment: Варяг-91, есть много устойчивых выражений. И что? Тут еще понимаете какая штука... Когда вопрос создается под готовый ответ (Справшивает Матвей Дёмин - отвечает Угрюм Веселов, потом наоборот), автор всегда будет требовать именно того ответа, который он прочитал на другом ресурсе, где нашел и сам вопрос... Ваши соображения всегда будут отвергнуты.

Comment: Я ответ не знаю, behemothus. Хотелось бы получить аргументированный ответ (со ссылками на толковые словари), а не ответ-ИМХО.